# Why does my code perform the later cout first?

Tags: c++

The following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool checkPerm(unsigned long long x){
    vector<unsigned long long> tester;
    string strx = to_string(x);
    int sizestrx = strx.size();
    int counter = 1;
    cout << "x is " << strx << " and its permutations are ";
    while (next_permutation(strx.begin(), strx.end())){
        cout << strx << " ";
        unsigned long long stoipermstrx = stoi(strx);
        tester.push_back(stoipermstrx);
    }
    cout << endl;
    int sizetester = tester.size();
    for (int j = 2; j <= 6; j++){
        cout << "j is " << j << ' ';
        for (int k = 0; k < sizetester; k++){
            if (j*x == tester[k]){
                cout << "counter increased because x, counter " << x << " " << counter << endl;
                counter++;
                if (counter == 6){
                    cout << "Number is " << x << endl;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        //cout << "Number " << x << " failed" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(){
    unsigned long long x = 1;
    for (double i = 0; ; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
        while (x < 1.67*pow(10, i)){
            if (i == 5)
                cout << x << endl;
            if (checkPerm(x)){
                cin.get();
            }
            x++;
        }
        x = pow(10, (i + 1));
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

has the following problems in this piece of code:

```
cout << "x is " << strx << " and its permutations are ";
while (next_permutation(strx.begin(), strx.end())){
    cout << strx << " ";
    unsigned long long stoipermstrx = stoi(strx);
    tester.push_back(stoipermstrx);
}
cout << endl;
int sizetester = tester.size();
for (int j = 2; j <= 6; j++){
    cout << "j is " << j << ' ';
    for (int k = 0; k < sizetester; k++){
        if (j*x == tester[k]){
            cout << "counter increased because x, counter " << x << " " << counter << endl;
            counter++;
            if (counter == 6){
                cout << "Number is " << x << endl;
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //cout << "Number " << x << " failed" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Here the output will be "j is j x is x and its permutations are (permutations of x)". HOWEVER, the console should print "x is x and its permutations are (permutations) j is j". The following sample output is given:

```
j is 2 x is 1355 and its permutations are 1535 1553 3155 3515 3551 5135 5153 531
5 5351 5513 5531
j is 2 x is 1356 and its permutations are 1365 1536 1563 1635 1653 3156 3165 351
6 3561 3615 3651 5136 5163 5316 5361 5613
```

Comment: [Cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f27c4cefbe165d34)

Comment: OP: What kind of optimizations are you compiling with?

Comment: Are you really using `cout` everywhere, not `cerr` anywhere?

Comment: Use the debugger, look at the actual compiled code and see what it is doing at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there are two (minor) things about this.  One, you are not looking at the value of  `sizetester` before printing the value of `j`, and you are not printing a newline after the value of `j`.  This means you are displaying the value of `j` for the *previous loop* at the beginning of your line for the *current 'x'*.  If I understand what your code is supposed to be doing, it seems to be doing it correctly -- it's just the way that the output is getting displayed that makes it confusing.

Try this:

```
int sizetester = tester.size();
for (int j = 2; j <= 6; j++){
    if (sizetester){                           // <-- added test (see below)
        cout << "j is " << j << '\n';          // <-- added newline
    }                                          // <--
```

The test against `sizetester` suppresses spurious printings of values for `j` - you later test that `(k < sizetester)` anyway.  The newline just prevents values of `j` from starting the line for *the next values of `x`*, which appears to be the cause of the confusing output.

Comment: Yes, thank you; the `cout << endl` seemed to cause the mistake